# Spring JPA fails to update a MySQL database which name contains the hyphen character

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to update a database using the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update` from JPA. But it's failing because the schema name contains a hyphen.

I'm using the following JPA configurations:

```
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Everything works fine using a name without the hyphen character. But, with the hyphen I get the following error:

```
2019-03-06 17:48:14.767  INFO 17296 --- [gine[Catalina]]] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
2019-03-06 17:48:14.770  INFO 17296 --- [gine[Catalina]]] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-03-06 17:48:14.852  INFO 17296 --- [gine[Catalina]]] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2019-03-06 17:48:15.163  INFO 17296 --- [gine[Catalina]]] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-3 - Starting...
2019-03-06 17:48:15.578  INFO 17296 --- [gine[Catalina]]] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-3 - Start completed.
2019-03-06 17:48:15.604  INFO 17296 --- [gine[Catalina]]] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Hibernate: alter table table-xxx.tablex add column column col_name_x varchar(255)
2019-03-06 17:48:16.857  WARN 17296 --- [gine[Catalina]]] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:580) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.migrateTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:297) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    ...
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-xxx.tablex add column col_name_x varchar(255)' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
```

Comment: seems is a minus char  .. not an hyphen  ..minus char in object name is not  allowed .. you should use another char eg_ underscore

Comment: Same problem using "minus".

Comment: You can't use minus  ... is not allowed

Comment: Found the solution: https://www.devglan.com/hibernate/hibernate-naming-strategy

Comment: you could also try adding backtics to object anme

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line in the `application.properties` solved the problem:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Initially, I thought that the `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy` was enough to treat tables and schema names, but it's not enough. There's also the [`physical-strategy`](https://www.devglan.com/hibernate/hibernate-naming-strategy).

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an old question, but I have stumbled upon it while I was searching for my problem, which was:

```
    @Column(name = "TEST-TEST") //the column name was 'TEST-TEST' in the database
    private String test;
```

And the error I was getting:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Ungültiger Spaltenname "TEST".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:265)

...
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'TEST'
```

And the solution I used was:

```
    @Column(name = "[TEST-TEST]") //the column name is 'TEST-TEST' in the database
    private String test;
```

Could this maybe solve your problem? I might have misunderstood the question, but this was my first result, when I was googling for the error, and maybe this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to quote your schema name with backquotes, e.g,

```
jpaPropertyMap.put("hibernate.default_catalog", "`foo-bar`")
```